# Looking for feedback on a flavour of Radix tree I wrote. The idea is speed on find() time if keys share common prefixes and are known ahead of time

Tags: c++, performance, collections, c++20

My project explores some ideas i've had regarding alternate data structures to the unorderd_map and map, and aiming the exploration to key sets with a non uniform distribution and key sets with common prefix's. I've posted the code to GitHub in full. see -> [FlashRadixTree](https://github.com/mattyv/FlashRadixTree/tree/main).

As you can see below for an ordered data structure it performs well against map for small keys, and very well against unordered_map for large keys.

### Performance Overview

#### 1.7KB key Apple M2 (ARM 64), Somoma 14.3.1 (23D60) CPU Cycles Comparison

```
FlashRadixTree::find() (using partial key match)
355.00 cycles/find() min,753.93 avg, 38,146.00 max 
map::find()
548.00 cycles/find() min, 714.92 avg, 15,022.00 max 
unordered_map::find()
711.00 cycles/find() min, 824.49 avg, 13,226.00 max
```

#### 6byte key

```
FlashRadixTree::find() (using partial key match)
136.00 cycles/find() min,   261.32 avg, 10,875.00 max 
map::find()
201.00 cycles/find() min,   273.10 avg,  4,517.00 max   
unordered_map::find()
154.00 cycles/find() min,   173.89 avg,   790.00 max
```

```
//
//  FlashRadixTree.hpp
//
//  Created by Matthew Varendorff on 26/2/2024.
//
//  GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
//  Version 3, 29 June 2007
//

#ifndef FlashRadixTree_hpp
#define FlashRadixTree_hpp

#define USE_SPLAY_TREE
//#define USE_CHAR_MAP

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
#include "SplayTree.hpp"
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
#include "CharMap.hpp"
#endif
#include <concepts>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#ifndef MAX_ALIGNMENT
#define MAX_ALIGNMENT
template <typename... Args>
constexpr size_t max_alignment() {
    return std::max({alignof(Args)...});
}
#endif

template<typename T>
concept StringLike = requires(T a, const T b, const char* s, std::size_t pos, std::size_t len, std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    typename T::value_type; // Ensure that T has a value_type member
    { a = s };
    { a == b } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    { a != b } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    { a.starts_with(b) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    { a.starts_with(s) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    { a[0] } -> std::convertible_to<typename T::value_type>;
    { a.begin() } -> std::forward_iterator;
    { a.end() } -> std::forward_iterator;
    { a.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
    { a.substr(pos, len) } -> std::convertible_to<T>;
    { a.length() } -> std::convertible_to<size_t>;
    T(s);
};
// Concept to check if a type supports streaming with '<<'
template<typename T>
concept Streaming = requires(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    { os << t } -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream&>;
};

// Concept to check if a type has an append() member function
template<typename T>
    concept HasAppend = requires(T a, const T& b) {
        { a.append(b) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
    };

enum class MatchMode {
    Prefix,
    Exact
};

template <StringLike Key, Streaming Value, MatchMode MatchMode = MatchMode::Exact>
class FlashRadixTree {
    
    static_assert(StringLike<Key>, "Key type must satisfy StringLike concept");
    static_assert(Streaming<Value>, "Value type must satisfy Streaming concept");

    
    enum class Sentinal { END, REND, NONE };
public:
    class FlashRadixTreeNode;
private:
    
    enum class IteratorDirection { FORWARD, REVERSE};
    template<IteratorDirection Direction>
    class XFlashRadixTreeIterator
    {
    private:
        FlashRadixTreeNode* _node;
        const FlashRadixTree* _tree;
        IteratorDirection _direction = Direction;
        bool _end = true;
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(FlashRadixTreeNode* node, const FlashRadixTree* tree) noexcept
        : _node(node), _tree(tree), _direction(Direction), _end(node == nullptr || tree == nullptr)
        {}
    public:
        //constructor to allow a reverse type from a forward
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::REVERSE>& other) noexcept
        : _node(other._node), _tree(other._tree), _direction(Direction), _end(other._end)
        {
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::FORWARD>& other) noexcept
        : _node(other._node), _tree(other._tree), _direction(Direction), _end(other._end)
        {
        }
        
        //assign a reverse iterator to a forward iterator
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::REVERSE>& other) noexcept
        {
            _node = other._node;
            _tree = other._tree;
            _direction = Direction;
            _end = other._end;
            return *this;
        }
        
        //assign a forward iterator to a reverse iterator
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::FORWARD>& other) noexcept
        {
            _node = other._node;
            _tree = other._tree;
            _direction = Direction;
            _end = other._end;
            return *this;
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator++() noexcept
        {
            if (_direction == IteratorDirection::FORWARD) {
                _node = _tree->_next(_node);
            } else {
                _node = _tree->_prev(_node);
            }
            _end = _node == nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator--() noexcept
        {
            if (_direction == IteratorDirection::FORWARD) {
                _node = _tree->_prev(_node);
            } else {
                _node = _tree->_next(_node);
            }
            _end = _node == nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator operator++(int) noexcept
        {
            XFlashRadixTreeIterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator operator--(int) noexcept
        {
            XFlashRadixTreeIterator tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        bool operator==(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) const noexcept
        {
            if(_end && other._end)
                return true;
            if(_node == nullptr && other._node == nullptr)
                return true;
            if(_node == nullptr || other._node == nullptr)
                return false;
            return *_node == *other._node;
        }
        bool operator!=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) const noexcept
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        
        constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode* operator->() noexcept
        {
            return _node;
        }
        constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode& operator*() noexcept
        {
            return *_node;
        }
        friend class FlashRadixTree;
    };
public:
    using iterator = XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::FORWARD>;
    using reverse_iterator = XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::REVERSE>;
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
    static constexpr size_t max_alignment_value_FlashRadixTreeNode = max_alignment<Key, Value, bool, SplayTree<typename Key::value_type, void*>,std::optional<Key>>();
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
    static constexpr size_t max_alignment_value_FlashRadixTreeNode = max_alignment<Key, Value, bool, CharMap<Value>,std::optional<Key>>();
#else
    static constexpr size_t max_alignment_value_FlashRadixTreeNode = max_alignment<Key, Value, bool, std::map<typename Key::value_type, void*>,std::optional<Key>>();
#endif
    class alignas(max_alignment_value_FlashRadixTreeNode) FlashRadixTreeNode {
    public:
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
        using Children = SplayTree<typename Key::value_type, FlashRadixTreeNode*>;
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
        using Children = CharMap<FlashRadixTreeNode*>;
#else
        using Children = std::map<typename Key::value_type, FlashRadixTreeNode*>;
#endif
        Children children;
        bool isEndOfWord = false;
        Value value = Value();
        Key prefix = Key();
        bool deleted = false;
        Sentinal sentinal = Sentinal::NONE;
        Children::iterator my_iterator;
        FlashRadixTreeNode* parent = nullptr;
    private:
        mutable std::optional<Key> fullKey;
    public:
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const Key& prefix, const Value&& value, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent ) noexcept
        : isEndOfWord(false), value(std::move(value)), prefix(prefix), deleted(false), sentinal(Sentinal::NONE), parent(parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const Key& prefix, const Value&& value, bool isEndOfWord, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent ) noexcept
        : isEndOfWord(isEndOfWord), value(std::move(value)), prefix(prefix), deleted(false), sentinal(Sentinal::NONE), parent(parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode(Sentinal sentinal) noexcept
        : isEndOfWord(false), value(), prefix(), deleted(false), sentinal(sentinal), parent(nullptr)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode() = default;
        ~FlashRadixTreeNode() = default;
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const FlashRadixTreeNode& ) = delete;
        FlashRadixTreeNode( FlashRadixTreeNode&& other) noexcept
        {
            children = std::move(other.children);
            isEndOfWord = other.isEndOfWord;
            value = std::move(other.value);
            prefix = std::move(other.prefix);
            deleted = other.deleted;
        }
        
        //operators
        FlashRadixTreeNode& operator=(const FlashRadixTreeNode& ) = delete;
        FlashRadixTreeNode& operator=(FlashRadixTreeNode&& other) noexcept
        {
            if(this != &other)
            {
                children = std::move(other.children);
                isEndOfWord = other.isEndOfWord;
                value = std::move(other.value);
                prefix = std::move(other.prefix);
                deleted = other.deleted;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        
        bool constexpr operator==(const FlashRadixTreeNode& other) const noexcept
        {
            return (isEndOfWord == other.isEndOfWord)
            && (prefix == other.prefix)
            && (deleted == other.deleted)
            && (sentinal == other.sentinal);
        }
        
        bool constexpr operator!=(const FlashRadixTreeNode& other) const noexcept
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        
        Key getFullKey() const noexcept
        {
            if(fullKey.has_value())
                return fullKey.value();
            
            //traverse up levels and prefix the key
            fullKey = prefix;
            if(parent == nullptr) {
                return fullKey.value();
            }
            //else traverse up the tree
            for(auto p = parent; p != nullptr; p = p->parent) {
                fullKey.value().insert(0, p->prefix);
            }
            return fullKey.value();
        }
        
        void setMyIterator(const Children::iterator& it) noexcept
        {
            my_iterator = it;
        }
        
        void setDeleted() noexcept
        {
            deleted = true;
        }
        
        void clear()
        {
            for(const auto& it : children) {
                auto child = it->value;
                if(child != nullptr) {
                    child->clear();
                    delete child;
                }
            }
            children.clear();
            isEndOfWord = false;
            value = Value();
            prefix = Key();
            deleted = false;
        }
    };
    using ValueType = Value;

private:
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _root;
    iterator _endIt = iterator(nullptr, nullptr);
    reverse_iterator _rendIt = reverse_iterator(nullptr, nullptr);
public:
    
    FlashRadixTree() : _root( new FlashRadixTreeNode()) {}
    ~FlashRadixTree() {
        clear();
    }
    
    FlashRadixTree(const FlashRadixTree& ) = delete;
    FlashRadixTree(FlashRadixTree&& other) noexcept
    : _root(other._root) {
        other._root = nullptr;
    }
    
    constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode* getRoot() const noexcept {
        return _root;
    }
    
    iterator begin() const noexcept {
        const auto node =  _getMinimum();
        if(node == nullptr) {
            return _endIt;
        }
        return iterator(node, this);
    }
    
    constexpr const iterator& end() const noexcept {
        return _endIt;
    }
    
    reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept {
        const auto node =  _getMaximum();
        if(node == nullptr) {
            return _rendIt;
        }
        return reverse_iterator(node, this);
    }
    
    constexpr const reverse_iterator& rend() const noexcept {
        return _rendIt;
    }
    
    iterator insert(const Key& key, Value&& value) noexcept
    {
        if (_root == nullptr) {
            // If the root doesn't exist, create it.
            _root = new FlashRadixTreeNode();
        }
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode* currentNode = _root;
        FlashRadixTreeNode* inserted = nullptr;
        Key remaining = key;
        
        while (!remaining.empty()) {
            const auto it = currentNode->children.find(remaining[0]);
            
            if( it != currentNode->children.end()) {
                // Found a common prefix, split the edge if necessary
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                const typename Key::value_type edgeKey = it->key;
                FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->value;
#else
                const typename Key::value_type edgeKey = it->first;
                FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->second;
#endif
                const Key& edge = childNode->prefix; // Assuming first is the key in the SplayTree
                
                // Determine the common prefix length
                size_t commonPrefixLength = 0;
                bool lineIsWholePrefix = false;
                while (commonPrefixLength < remaining.size() && commonPrefixLength < edge.size()
                       && remaining[commonPrefixLength] == edge[commonPrefixLength]) {
                    ++commonPrefixLength;
                    lineIsWholePrefix = commonPrefixLength == remaining.size();
                }
                
                if (commonPrefixLength < edge.length()) {
                    // Split the edge
                    const Key& commonPrefix = edge.substr(0, commonPrefixLength);
                    const Key& suffixEdge = edge.substr(commonPrefixLength);
                    
                    
                    // Create a new node for the common prefix
                    auto* newChild = new FlashRadixTreeNode(commonPrefix, std::move((lineIsWholePrefix ? std::move(value) : Value())), lineIsWholePrefix, currentNode);
                    
                    // The new node should adopt the existing child node
                    childNode->prefix = suffixEdge;
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE)  || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                    auto it = newChild->children.insert(suffixEdge[0], std::move(childNode));
#else
                    auto it = newChild->children.emplace(suffixEdge[0], std::move(childNode));
#endif
                    childNode->parent = newChild;
                    childNode->setMyIterator(it);
                    currentNode->children.erase(edgeKey);
                    
                    // Insert the new child with the common prefix in the current node's children
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                    auto itChild = currentNode->children.insert(commonPrefix[0], std::move(newChild));
                    currentNode = itChild->value;
#else
                    auto itChild = currentNode->children.emplace(commonPrefix[0], std::move(newChild));
                    currentNode = itChild.first->second;
#endif
                    newChild->setMyIterator(itChild);
                } else {
                    // Entire edge is a common prefix, proceed with the child node
                    currentNode = childNode;
                    if(currentNode->isEndOfWord && currentNode->deleted)
                    {
                        currentNode->value = std::move(value);
                        currentNode->deleted = false;
                        inserted = currentNode;
                    }
                }
                
                // Update the remaining part of the key to insert
                remaining = remaining.substr(commonPrefixLength);
            } else {
                // No common prefix found, create a new edge for the remaining part of the key
                auto newNode = new FlashRadixTreeNode(remaining, std::move(value), currentNode);
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                auto it = currentNode->children.insert(remaining[0], newNode);
                currentNode = it->value;
#else
                auto it = currentNode->children.emplace(remaining[0], newNode);
                currentNode = it.first->second;
#endif
                newNode->setMyIterator(it);
                currentNode->isEndOfWord = true;
                
                // As we've inserted the rest of the key, we're done
                remaining = Key();
                inserted = currentNode;
            }
        }
        if(inserted == nullptr)
            return _endIt;
        else
            return iterator(inserted, this);
    }
    
        
    //_erase() requires the function append() which will not work on a string_view.
    //in which case we use mark_erase()
    bool erase(const Key& key) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr(HasAppend<Key>)
            return _erase(key);
        else
            return _mark_erase(key);
    }
    
    void print() const noexcept {
        _printRecursively(' ', _root, 0);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    iterator find(const Key& key) const noexcept {
        if (key.empty()) {
            return _endIt; // An empty key cannot be found.
        }
        
        const FlashRadixTreeNode* currentNode = _root;
        char keyPrefix = key[0];
        Key remaining = key;
        size_t seen = 0;
        while( currentNode != nullptr)
        {
            auto it = currentNode->children.find(keyPrefix);

            if(it != currentNode->children.end())
            {
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                currentNode = it->value;
#else
                currentNode = it->second;
#endif
                if(MatchMode == MatchMode::Prefix && //if we are in prefix mode we can stop if we find the prefix
                   currentNode->isEndOfWord &&
                       (currentNode->children.empty() ||//if there are no children below this key we have our winner
                        currentNode->prefix.size() == remaining.size())) //if the prefix is the same size as the remaining key we can match on that also
                {
                    if(currentNode->deleted)
                        return _endIt;
                    else
                        return iterator(const_cast<FlashRadixTreeNode*>( currentNode), this);
                }
                else if(currentNode->isEndOfWord && remaining == currentNode->prefix) //else we no choice but to check the whole word
                {
                    if(currentNode->deleted)
                        return _endIt;
                    else
                        return iterator(const_cast<FlashRadixTreeNode*>( currentNode), this);
                }
                else if( key.size() > (seen += currentNode->prefix.size()) )
                {
                    //we look for children below looking at the next possible prefix
                    keyPrefix = key[seen];
                    remaining = key.substr(seen);
                }
            }
            else
                return _endIt; //assume doesn't exist
            
        }
        return _endIt;
    }
    
    //delete all items non recursively
    void clear() noexcept {
        if(_root != nullptr)
            _root->clear();
        _root = nullptr;
    }
        
private:
    void _printRecursively(const typename Key::value_type& key, FlashRadixTreeNode* node, int level) const noexcept{
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
            std::cout << "  ";
        }
        
        std::cout << "K: " << key << " P: " << node->prefix << " (" << node->value << ")" << " is EOW " << (node->isEndOfWord ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;
        
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE)
        for(const auto& it : node->children)
        {
            _printRecursively(it->key, it->value, level + 1);
        }
#elif defined( USE_CHAR_MAP)
        node->children.inOrderAndOp([&](const auto& node)->bool {
            _printRecursively(node->key, node->value, level + 1);
            return true;
        });
#else
        for (const auto& it : node->children) {
            _printRecursively(it.first, it.second, level + 1);
        }
#endif
    }
    
    void inOrderAndOpRecursively( FlashRadixTreeNode* node, const Key& key, const std::function<bool(const Key&, const Value&)>& op) const noexcept {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return;
        }
        
        node->children.inOrderAndOp([this, &op]( auto splay)->bool
                                    {
                                        this->inOrderAndOpRecursively(splay->value, splay->value->prefix, op);
                                        return true;
                                    });
        if(!op(key, node->value))
            return;
    }
        
        
    bool _mark_erase(const Key& key) noexcept
    {
        auto found = find(key);
        if (found == end()) {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            found->deleted = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    bool _erase(const Key& key) noexcept {
        if (key.empty()) {
            return false; // Cannot erase an empty key
        }

        FlashRadixTreeNode* currentNode = _root;
        FlashRadixTreeNode* parentNode = nullptr;
        Key remainingKey = key;

        // Step 1: Find the node
        while (currentNode != nullptr && !remainingKey.empty()) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            auto it = currentNode->children.find(remainingKey.at(0));
            
            if (it == currentNode->children.end()) {
                return false; // Key not found
            }

            const Key& nodePrefix = it->value->prefix;
            FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->value;

            if (remainingKey.starts_with(nodePrefix)) {
                // Prefix matches, move to the next node
                const auto nodePrefixSize = nodePrefix.size();
                remainingKey = remainingKey.substr(nodePrefixSize);
                currentNode = childNode;
            } else {
                // Prefix does not match the remaining key
                return false; // Key not found
            }
        }

        // If the end of the key has been reached and it's not marked as an end of a word, the key does not exist
        if (!currentNode->isEndOfWord) {
            return false;
        }

        // Step 2: Delete the node or unmark the end of the word
        currentNode->isEndOfWord = false; // Unmark as the end of a word

        // If the current node has has more than one child then we're done
        if (currentNode->children.size() > 1) {
            return true;
        }

        // Step 3: Clean up the tree
        if ((parentNode != nullptr) && (currentNode->children.size() <= 1) && !currentNode->isEndOfWord) {

            // Remove the leaf node if it does not have any children
            if(currentNode->children.empty())
                parentNode->children.erase(currentNode->prefix.at(0));

            // If the parent node is now a leaf and is not an end-of-word node, set it as the current node for the next iteration
            if (parentNode->children.empty() && !parentNode->isEndOfWord) {
                currentNode = parentNode;
                if (parentNode != nullptr) {
                    remainingKey = parentNode->prefix;
                }
            }
            else if(currentNode->children.size() == 1 && !currentNode->isEndOfWord)
            {
                auto remainingChild = currentNode->children.root()->value;
                currentNode->prefix.append(remainingChild->prefix);
                currentNode->value = remainingChild->value;
                currentNode->isEndOfWord = remainingChild->isEndOfWord;
                currentNode->children = std::move(remainingChild->children);
                delete remainingChild;
            }
            //if the parent node has only one child we can compress (unless we're root. that makes no sense)
            else if(parentNode != _root && parentNode->children.size() == 1 && !parentNode->isEndOfWord)
            {
                auto remainingChild = parentNode->children.root()->value;
                parentNode->prefix.append(remainingChild->prefix);
                parentNode->value = remainingChild->value;
                parentNode->isEndOfWord = remainingChild->isEndOfWord;
                parentNode->children = std::move(remainingChild->children);
                delete currentNode;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _getMinimum() const noexcept
    {
        if(_root == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        
        auto* children = &_root->children;
        auto it = children->begin();
        while( children != nullptr)
        {
            if(it->value->isEndOfWord)
                break;
            const auto check = children->begin();
            if(check == children->end())
                break;
            it = check;
            children = &it->value->children;
        }
        return it->value;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _getMaximum() const noexcept
    {
        if(_root == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        
        auto* children = &_root->children;
        auto it = children->rbegin();
        while( children != nullptr)
        {
            const auto check = children->rbegin();
            if(check == children->rend())
                break;
            it = check;
            children = &it->value->children;
        }
        return it->value;
    }
        
    
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _next(FlashRadixTreeNode* node) const noexcept
    {
        if(node == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        
        //next will be first node on lower level if there is one, and its ann end of word and not deleted
        //otherwise it will be the next node on the same level that is an end of word and not deleted
        //or if we reach the end of the current level we go up one level and repeat
        auto* currentNode = node;
        auto it = node->my_iterator;
        while(!currentNode->children.empty())
        {
            it = currentNode->children.begin();
            if(it != currentNode->children.end() ) {
                if( it->value->isEndOfWord && !it->value->deleted)
                    return it->value;
                currentNode = it->value; //else cycle down
            }
        }
        // we iterate once at the current level
        ++it;
        
        //if we reach the end of the current level we go up one level and repeat
        if(it == currentNode->children.end() && currentNode->parent != nullptr)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->parent;
            it = currentNode->my_iterator;
            ++it;
        }
        //if this node is not end of word or is deleted we go down
        if(it != currentNode->children.end() && (!it->value->isEndOfWord || it->value->deleted))
        {
            currentNode = it->value;
            while(!currentNode->children.empty())
            {
                it = currentNode->children.begin();
                if(it != currentNode->children.end() ) {
                    if( it->value->isEndOfWord && !it->value->deleted)
                        return it->value;
                    currentNode = it->value; //else cycle down
                }
            }
        }
        if(currentNode->parent == nullptr || it == currentNode->parent->children.end())
            return nullptr;
        return it->value;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _prev(FlashRadixTreeNode* node) const noexcept
    {
        if(node == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        
        //next will be next the next node on the same level that is an end of word and not deleted
        //otherwise it will be node on the max child of the next node on the level above.
        auto* currentNode = node;
        typename FlashRadixTreeNode::Children::reverse_iterator  it = node->my_iterator; //explicitly use reverse here as my_iterator is a forward iterator
    
        ++it;
        
        //if we reach the end of the current level we go up one level and repeat
        if(it == currentNode->children.rend() && currentNode->parent != nullptr)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->parent;
            it = currentNode->my_iterator;
            if(*it != nullptr && it != currentNode->children.rend() && (!it->value->isEndOfWord || it->value->deleted))
            {
                ++it;
            }
            while(it == currentNode->children.rend() && currentNode->parent != nullptr) //if we reach the end of the current level we go up one level and repeat
            {
                currentNode = currentNode->parent;
                it = currentNode->my_iterator;
                ++it;
                if(it != currentNode->children.rend())
                    currentNode = it->value;
            }
        }
        //if this node is not end of word or is deleted we go all the way down
        if(it != currentNode->children.rend() && !it->value->children.empty() && (!it->value->isEndOfWord || it->value->deleted))
        {
            currentNode = it->value;
            while(!currentNode->children.empty())
            {
                it = currentNode->children.rbegin();
                if(it != currentNode->children.rend() ) {
                    currentNode = it->value; //else cycle down
                }
            }

        }
        if(currentNode->parent == nullptr || it == currentNode->children.rend())
            return nullptr;
        return it->value;
    }
    
};


template <Streaming Key, Streaming Value, MatchMode FindMode = MatchMode::Exact>
class FlashRadixTreeSerializer {
    static_assert(StringLike<Key>, "Key type must satisfy StringLike concept");
    static_assert(Streaming<Value>, "Value type must satisfy Streaming concept");
public:
    std::string serialize(const FlashRadixTree<Key, Value, FindMode>& tree) {
        return serializeNode(tree.getRoot());
    }
    
    std::string format(const std::string& serialized) {
        //iterate though string and insert new lines and tabs to format according to grammar
        std::string formatted;
        int indent = 0;
        for (auto c : serialized) {
            if (c == '[') {
                formatted += c;
                formatted += '\n';
                indent++;
                for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    formatted += '\t';
                }
            } else if (c == ']') {
                formatted += '\n';
                indent--;
                for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    formatted += '\t';
                }
                formatted += c;
            } else {
                formatted += c;
            }
        }
        return formatted;
    }

private:
    std::string serializeNode(const typename FlashRadixTree<Key, Value, FindMode>::FlashRadixTreeNode* node) const  {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return "";
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "+[" << node->prefix << "," << node->value << "," << (node->isEndOfWord ? "√": "*")  << (node->deleted ? "X" : "") << ",<";

        if(node->children.empty())
            ss << "-";
        else
        {
            bool first = true;
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
            /*node->children.inOrderAndOp([&ss, &first](const SplayTree<typename Key::value_type, typename FlashRadixTree<Key, Value, FindMode>::FlashRadixTreeNode*>::splay* childPair) -> bool {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(childPair->value);
                first = false;
                return true;
            });*/
            for(const auto& it : node->children)
            {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(it->value);
                first = false;
            }
#elif defined( USE_CHAR_MAP)
            node->children.inOrderAndOp([&ss, &first](const auto& childPair) -> bool {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(childPair.value);
                first = false;
                return true;
            });
#else
            for (const auto& childPair : node->children) {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(childPair.second);
                first = false;
            }
#endif
        }
        
        ss << ">]";
        return ss.str();
    }
   
};

#endif /* FlashRadixTree */
```

Answer (score 4):

## About `StringLike`

The way you wrote the concept `StringLike` is frowned upon. It's basically testing all the aspects of the `T`'s interface that you are using in your code. However, with so many clauses it's easy to make mistakes. Another issue is checking directly for member functions like `a.size()`, when it's much better to check if the much more generic `std::size(a)` works.

It would be great if this could be simplified in some way. One way is to make use of `std::string_view`: if `T` is convertible to that, then you can use all of `std::string_view`'s interface to access `T`:

```
template<typename T>
concept StringLike = std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>;
```

However, this doesn't ensure that `T` itself has `size()`, `starts_with()` and so on. You need to convert `T` to a `std::string_view` before you can use it. However, a helper function might make that easy:

```
std::string_view get_prefix() const {
    return prefix;
}
```

So then you can write code like: `currentNode->get_prefix().size()`.

Alternatively, consider removing `StringLike` altogether, and just use `std::string`. If you want to make the string type configurable, then I think it would be much more useful to be able to change the character type:

```
template<Streaming Value, …, typename CharT = char>
class FlashRadixTree {
    using Key = std::basic_string<CharT>;
    …
};
```

## The `static_assert()`s will never trigger

Since the concepts are already checked at class instantiation time, the `static_assert()` statements you added will never trigger.

## Iterator direction

Why is the iterator direction both a template parameter and a member variable? This doesn't make sense. Choose one. I also don't think it makes much sense to be able to assign one type of iterator to another. If you really want to be able to change the direction of an iterator, then you could also do that by having an explicit member function for that, that returns an iterator of the other direction type.

## Don't use `new` and `delete`

Whenever possible, avoid manual calls to `new` and `delete`, and instead use smart pointers or containers to manage memory for you. For example, `std::map` can allocate `FlashRadixTreeNode`s directly:

```
using Children = std::map<typename Key::value_type, FlashRadixTreeNode>;
```

And for `_root` you don't need anything at all; since you always allocate it, why not just store it by value?

```
FlashRadixTreeNode root;
```

Manual memory management often leads to memory leaks or worse. And you indeed have a memory leak: in `FlashRadixTree::clear()` you clear the children of the root node, but you forgot to `delete` the root node itself.

## Redundant initialization of member variables

I see you use both default member initialization and member initialization lists at the same time, for the same member variables. That's just code duplication. If you have a default member initializer for a given member variable, just don't add that variable again to the member initializer list of a constructor if that will just initialize it to the same value.

Conversely, if you always override the default member intializer value in the constructor, remove the default member initializer.

## Avoid `noexcept`

You should use `noexcept` only if you are absolutely sure nothing will throw. But many things can throw exceptions. Especially if you template your code, you don't know the properties of the template types. And even if you do, are you sure you know what throws and what doesn't? For example, none of `std::string`'s assignment operators are `noexcept`, so any function you have that moves `std::string`s should not be `noexcept`.

I strongly recommend you remove `noexcept` everywhere in your code; most of it is incorrect, and it doesn't give you a performance benefit anyway.

## Remove `alignas()`

What is going on with the alignment of `FlashRadixTreeNode`? Why calculate the alignment yourself? The compiler already does that itself. You also forgot to take the alignment of `Sentinal` and `Children::iterator` into account.

Comment: Firstly... thank you very much for your kind review. I fully expected to hear nothing form this post. This is highly useful. 
I plan to make these changes one at a time and here necessary check performance impact as the speed is of importance to me.

Comment: removing alignas made no difference to performance so I've removed that

Comment: I've removed noexcept in most cases, apart from functions where the class controls the types such as pointer or other member variable not defined by template arguments. performance impact seems null.

Comment: I've gone with the approach of forcing the key type to be either a string or string view, for lack of a better option. 
I've updated to use unique_prt's. 
Iteration direction is done as you suggested.
Same with member variable initialisation and static assert. 
all in all quite happy. so thanks.
I've decided to take things further and do better management of out of memory conditions, and allowing allocators. 
I've also redone the iterators as they were far too complex initially. 
In time I'd also like to adapt the interface to be more similar to std::map so its a drop in replacement.

Comment: one thing I have noticed is that allowing for custom allocators seems to have had slight negative impact on performance for inserts. I'm not 100% sure why that is, but I assume its due to some inability of the compiler to optimise some allocator code compared to the standard new and delete options.

Comment: @ver2 sounds like you made some nice improvements! Consider posting your updated code as a new question here on CodeReview.

Comment: will do.thanks @G. Sliepen.

Comment: here we are https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291202/looking-for-feedback-on-a-flavour-of-radix-tree-i-wrote-this-is-version-2-of-th