# Looking for feedback on a flavour of Radix tree I wrote. This is version 2 of the class original posted on this forum

Tags: c++, performance, collections, c++20

My project explores some ideas i've had regarding alternate data structures to the unorderd_map and map, and aiming the exploration to key sets with a non uniform distribution and key sets with common prefix's. I've posted the code to GitHub in full. see -> [FlashRadixTree](https://github.com/mattyv/FlashRadixTree).

I posted a request for review here for version 1.
[Original review here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291042/looking-for-feedback-on-a-flavour-of-radix-tree-i-wrote-the-idea-is-speed-on-fi/291044#291044)

In this version, in addition to applying the code review changes, I've added the ability to specify an allocator but I've noticed that it hits performance somewhat (see below). I'm interested to see general feedback, but specifically I'm interested in this allocator issue.

**Original Performance of find()**

**6byte key Apple M2 (ARM 64), Somoma 14.3.1 (23D60) CPU Cycles Comparison**

```
FlashRadixTree::find() (using partial key match)
136.00 cycles/find() min,   261.32 avg, 10,875.00 max 
map::find()
```

**Using allowing allocators. but not specifying custom allocator (i.e. std::allocator)**

```
FlashRadixTree::find() (using partial key match)
175.00 cycles/find() min,   308.43 avg, 13,513.00 max
```

*Please note there are some outstanding items I'm tracking. The main one being that my alternate data structures (map/char_map) are not compiling right now. I plan to come back to this in some time.*

```
//
//  FlashRadixTree.hpp
//
//  Created by Matthew Varendorff on 26/2/2024.
//
//  GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
//  Version 3, 29 June 2007
//

#ifndef FlashRadixTree_hpp
#define FlashRadixTree_hpp

#define USE_SPLAY_TREE
//#define USE_CHAR_MAP

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
#include "SplayTree.hpp"
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
#include "CharMap.hpp"
#endif
#include <concepts>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>



template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>> make_unique_alloc(Alloc alloc, Args&&... args)
{
    using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>;
    using pointer = typename AllocTraits::pointer;

    // Allocate space for one object of type T
    pointer ptr = AllocTraits::allocate(alloc, 1);

    // Construct an object of type T with the provided arguments
    AllocTraits::construct(alloc, ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // Create a custom deleter as a lambda function that captures the allocator by value
    auto deleter = [alloc](T* ptr) mutable {
        AllocTraits::destroy(alloc, ptr); // Call destructor
        AllocTraits::deallocate(alloc, ptr, 1); // Deallocate memory
    };

    // Define the deleter type
    using DeleterType = std::function<void(T*)>;

    // Create and return a unique_ptr with the custom deleter
    return std::unique_ptr<T, DeleterType>(ptr, deleter);
}



template<typename T>
concept IsBasicString = requires {
    typename T::traits_type;
    typename T::allocator_type;
    // Check if T is an instantiation of std::basic_string
    requires std::is_same_v<T, std::basic_string<typename T::value_type,
                                                 typename T::traits_type,
                                                 typename T::allocator_type>>;
};

template<typename T>
concept IsBasicStringView = requires {
    typename T::traits_type;
    // Check if T is an instantiation of std::basic_string_view
    requires std::is_same_v<T, std::basic_string_view<typename T::value_type,
                                                      typename T::traits_type>>;
};

template<typename T>
concept BasicStringOrBasicStringView = IsBasicString<T> || IsBasicStringView<T>;

// Concept to check if a type supports streaming with '<<'
template<typename T>
concept Streaming = requires(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    { os << t } -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream&>;
};

enum class MatchMode {
    Prefix,
    Exact
};


template <BasicStringOrBasicStringView Key, Streaming Value, MatchMode MatchMode = MatchMode::Exact, typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Value>>>
class FlashRadixTree {
    enum class Sentinal { END, REND, NONE };

public:
    template<class Parent>
    struct FlashRadixTreeNodeBase
    {
        FlashRadixTreeNodeBase() = default;
        FlashRadixTreeNodeBase(bool isEndOfWord, Value&& value, const Key& prefix, Parent* parent)
        : isEndOfWord(isEndOfWord), value(std::move(value)), prefix(prefix), parent(parent)
        {};
        FlashRadixTreeNodeBase(bool isEndOfWord, const Value& value, const Key& prefix, Parent* parent)
        : isEndOfWord(isEndOfWord), value(value), prefix(prefix), parent(parent)
        {};
        
        //move and move assignment
        FlashRadixTreeNodeBase(FlashRadixTreeNodeBase&& other) noexcept
        {
            isEndOfWord = other.isEndOfWord;
            value = std::move(other.value);
            prefix = std::move(other.prefix);
            deleted = other.deleted;
            next = other.next;
            prev = other.prev;
            other.next = nullptr;
            other.prev = nullptr;
        }
        FlashRadixTreeNodeBase& operator=(FlashRadixTreeNodeBase&& other) noexcept
        {
            if(this != &other)
            {
                isEndOfWord = other.isEndOfWord;
                value = std::move(other.value);
                prefix = std::move(other.prefix);
                deleted = other.deleted;
                next = other.next;
                prev = other.prev;
                other.next = nullptr;
                other.prev = nullptr;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        bool constexpr operator==(const FlashRadixTreeNodeBase& other) const
        {
            return (isEndOfWord == other.isEndOfWord)
            && (prefix == other.prefix)
            && (deleted == other.deleted);
        }
        bool constexpr operator!=(const FlashRadixTreeNodeBase& other) const
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        Key getFullKey() const
        {
            if(fullKey.has_value())
                return fullKey.value();
            
            //traverse up levels and prefix the key
            fullKey = prefix;
            if(parent == nullptr) {
                return fullKey.value();
            }
            //else traverse up the tree
            for(auto p = parent; p != nullptr; p = p->parent) {
                fullKey.value().insert(0, p->prefix);
            }
            return fullKey.value();
        }
        
        void setDeleted()  noexcept
        {
            deleted = true;
        }
        
        void clear()
        {
            isEndOfWord = false;
            value = Value();
            prefix = Key();
            deleted = false;
        }
        
        bool isEndOfWord = false;
        Value value = Value();
        Key prefix = Key();
        bool deleted = false;
        Parent* next = nullptr;
        Parent* prev = nullptr;
        Parent* parent = nullptr;
    private:
        mutable std::optional<std::string> fullKey;
    };
    
    class FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner;
    
    class FlashRadixTreeNode : public FlashRadixTreeNodeBase<FlashRadixTreeNode> {
        using BaseType = FlashRadixTreeNodeBase<FlashRadixTreeNode>;
    public:
        using TreeNodePtr = std::unique_ptr<FlashRadixTreeNode, std::function<void(FlashRadixTreeNode*)>>;
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
        using Children = SplayTree<typename Key::value_type, TreeNodePtr, Allocator>;
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
        using Children = CharMap<TreeNodePtr>;
#else
        using Children = std::map<typename Key::value_type, TreeNodePtr>;
#endif
        Children children = Children(Allocator());
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const Key& prefix, Value&& value, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent)
        : BaseType(false, std::forward<Value>(value), prefix, parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const Key& prefix, Value&& value, bool isEndOfWord, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent)
        : BaseType(isEndOfWord, std::forward<Value>(value), prefix, parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNode() = default;
        ~FlashRadixTreeNode() = default;
        FlashRadixTreeNode(const FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& ) = delete;
        FlashRadixTreeNode( FlashRadixTreeNode&& other) noexcept
        : BaseType(std::move(other))
        {
            children = std::move(other.children);
        }
        //operators
        FlashRadixTreeNode& operator=(const FlashRadixTreeNode& ) = delete;
        FlashRadixTreeNode& operator=(FlashRadixTreeNode&& other) noexcept
        {
            if(this != &other)
            {
                BaseType::operator=(std::move(other));
                children = std::move(other.children);
            }
            return *this;
        }

        void clear()
        {
            children.clear();
            FlashRadixTreeNodeBase<FlashRadixTreeNode>::clear();
        }
    };
    
    class FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner : public FlashRadixTreeNodeBase<FlashRadixTreeNode>
    {
        using BaseType = FlashRadixTreeNodeBase<FlashRadixTreeNode>;
    public:
        using TreeNodePtr = FlashRadixTreeNode*;
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
        using Children = SplayTree<typename Key::value_type, TreeNodePtr, Allocator>;
#elif defined USE_CHAR_MAP
        using Children = CharMap<TreeNodePtr>;
#else
        using Children = std::map<typename Key::value_type, TreeNodePtr>;
#endif
        Children children = Children(Allocator());
        
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner(const Key& prefix, Value&& value, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent)
        : BaseType(false, std::forward<Value>(value), prefix, parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner(const Key& prefix, const Value& value, bool isEndOfWord, FlashRadixTreeNode* parent)
        : BaseType(isEndOfWord, value, prefix, parent)
        {};
        
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner() = default;
        ~FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner() = default;
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner(const FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& other)
        :BaseType(other)
        {
            children = other.children;
        }
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner( FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner&& other) noexcept
        : BaseType(std::move(other))
        {
            children = std::move(other.children);
        }
        //operators
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& operator=(const FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& other )
        {
            if(this != &other)
            {
                BaseType::operator=(other);
                children = other.children;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& operator=(FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner&& other) noexcept
        {
            if(this != &other)
            {
                BaseType::operator=(std::move(other));
                children = std::move(other.children);
            }
            return *this;
        }
    };
    
    using ValueType = Value;

private:

    
    enum class IteratorDirection { FORWARD, REVERSE};
    template<IteratorDirection Direction>
    class XFlashRadixTreeIterator
    {
    private:
        FlashRadixTreeNode* _node;
        const FlashRadixTree* _tree;
        IteratorDirection _direction = Direction;
        bool _end = true;
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(FlashRadixTreeNode* node, const FlashRadixTree* tree)
        : _node(node), _tree(tree), _direction(Direction), _end(node == nullptr || tree == nullptr)
        {}
    public:
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator() noexcept = default;
        ~XFlashRadixTreeIterator() = default;
        
        // Default copy constructor - used for same type
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) noexcept = default;

        // Default copy assignment operator - used for same type
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) noexcept = default;

        // Prevent cross-direction copying and assignment using a deleted function template
        template<IteratorDirection OtherDirection>
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<OtherDirection>&) = delete;
       
        template<IteratorDirection OtherDirection>
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator<OtherDirection>&) = delete;
        
        //converter functions to convert form forward to reverse and vice versa
        //template<IteratorDirection OtherDirection>
        auto get_other_direction() const  noexcept {
            if constexpr (Direction == IteratorDirection::FORWARD) {
                return XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::REVERSE>(_node, _tree);
            } else {
                return XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::FORWARD>(_node, _tree);
            }
        }

        
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator++()  noexcept
        {
            if (_direction == IteratorDirection::FORWARD) {
                do{
                    _node = _node->next;
                }while(_node != nullptr && (!_node->isEndOfWord || _node->deleted));
            }
            else {
                do{
                    _node = _node->prev;
                }while(_node != nullptr && (!_node->isEndOfWord || _node->deleted));
            }
            _end = _node == nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator& operator--()  noexcept
        {
            if (_direction == IteratorDirection::FORWARD) {
                do{
                    _node = _node->prev;
                }while(_node != nullptr && (!_node->isEndOfWord || _node->deleted));
            }
            else {
                do{
                    _node = _node->next;
                }while(_node != nullptr && (!_node->isEndOfWord || _node->deleted));
            }
            _end = _node == nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator operator++(int)  noexcept
        {
            XFlashRadixTreeIterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        XFlashRadixTreeIterator operator--(int)  noexcept
        {
            XFlashRadixTreeIterator tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        bool operator==(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) const
        {
            if(_tree != other._tree)
                return false;
            if(_end && other._end)
                return true;
            if(_node == nullptr && other._node == nullptr)
                return true;
            if(_node == nullptr || other._node == nullptr)
                return false;
            return *_node == *other._node;
        }
        bool operator!=(const XFlashRadixTreeIterator& other) const
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        
        constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode* operator->()
        {
            return _node;
        }
        constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode& operator*()
        {
            return *_node;
        }
        friend class FlashRadixTree;
    };
public:
    
    using iterator = XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::FORWARD>;
    using reverse_iterator = XFlashRadixTreeIterator<IteratorDirection::REVERSE>;
    using TreeNodeAllocator = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<FlashRadixTreeNode>;
    using UniquePtrAlloc = std::unique_ptr<FlashRadixTreeNode, std::function<void(FlashRadixTreeNode*)>>;
private:
    TreeNodeAllocator _nodeAllocator;
    UniquePtrAlloc _root;
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _firstWord = nullptr;
    iterator _endIt = iterator(nullptr, this);
    reverse_iterator _rendIt = reverse_iterator(nullptr, this);
    size_t _size = 0;
public:
    
    FlashRadixTree(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())  noexcept
    : _nodeAllocator(alloc),
    _root(make_unique_alloc<FlashRadixTreeNode>(_nodeAllocator))
    {
    }
    ~FlashRadixTree() {
        clear();
    }
    
    FlashRadixTree(const FlashRadixTree& ) = delete;
    FlashRadixTree(FlashRadixTree&& other) noexcept
    : _nodeAllocator(std::move(other._nodeAllocator)), _root(std::move(other._root)), _firstWord(other._firstWord), _size(other._size) {
        other._firstWord = nullptr;
        other._size = 0;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTree& operator=(FlashRadixTree&& other) noexcept {
        if(this != &other) {
            clear();
            _nodeAllocator = std::move(other._nodeAllocator);
            _root = std::move(other._root);
            _firstWord = other._firstWord;
            _size = other._size;
            other._firstWord = nullptr;
            other._size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    constexpr FlashRadixTreeNode* getRoot() const  {
        return _root.get();
    }
    
    constexpr size_t size() const  noexcept {
        return _size;
    }
    
    iterator begin() const  noexcept {
        const auto node =  _getMinimum();
        if(node == nullptr) {
            return _endIt;
        }
        return iterator(node, this);
    }
    
    constexpr const iterator& end() const  noexcept {
        return _endIt;
    }
    
    reverse_iterator rbegin() const  noexcept {
        const auto node =  _getMaximum(_root.get());
        if(node == nullptr) {
            return _rendIt;
        }
        return reverse_iterator(node, this);
    }
    
    constexpr const reverse_iterator& rend() const  noexcept {
        return _rendIt;
    }
    
    iterator insert(const Key& key, Value&& value)
    {
        std::optional<FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner> rollback;
        FlashRadixTreeNode* rollbackLocation = nullptr;
        
        if (_root == nullptr) {
            // If the root doesn't exist, create it.
            _root = make_unique_alloc<FlashRadixTreeNode>(_nodeAllocator);
        }
        
        try
        {
            FlashRadixTreeNode* currentNode = _root.get();
            FlashRadixTreeNode* inserted = nullptr;
            Key remaining = key;
            
            while (!remaining.empty()) {
                const typename FlashRadixTreeNode::Children::iterator& it = currentNode->children.find(remaining[0]);
                
                if( it != currentNode->children.end()) {
                    // Found a common prefix, split the edge if necessary
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                    const typename Key::value_type edgeKey = it->key;
                    FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->value.get();
#else
                    const typename Key::value_type edgeKey = it->first;
                    FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->second.get();
#endif
                    const Key& edge = childNode->prefix; // Assuming first is the key in the SplayTree
                    
                    // Determine the common prefix length
                    size_t commonPrefixLength = 0;
                    bool lineIsWholePrefix = false;
                    while (commonPrefixLength < remaining.size() && commonPrefixLength < edge.size()
                           && remaining[commonPrefixLength] == edge[commonPrefixLength]) {
                        ++commonPrefixLength;
                        lineIsWholePrefix = commonPrefixLength == remaining.size();
                    }
                    
                    if (commonPrefixLength < edge.length()) {
                        // Split the edge
                        const Key& commonPrefix = edge.substr(0, commonPrefixLength);
                        const Key& suffixEdge = edge.substr(commonPrefixLength);
                        
                        
                        // Create a new node for the common prefix
                        auto newChild = make_unique_alloc<FlashRadixTreeNode>(_nodeAllocator, commonPrefix, std::move((lineIsWholePrefix ? std::forward<Value>(value) : Value())), lineIsWholePrefix, currentNode);
                        inserted = newChild.get();
                        
                        //new node will take over location of old node in the list followed by existing split node
                        if(_firstWord == childNode)
                            _firstWord = inserted;
                        inserted->prev = childNode->prev;
                        childNode->prev = inserted;
                        inserted->next = childNode;
                        
                        // The new node should adopt the existing child node
                        rollback = _copyFromOwnerNode(childNode);
                        rollbackLocation = childNode;
                        childNode->prefix = suffixEdge;
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE)  || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                        newChild->children.insert(suffixEdge[0], std::move(it->value));
#else
                        newChild->children.emplace(suffixEdge[0], std::move(it->value));
#endif
                        childNode->parent = newChild.get();
                        
                        // Insert the new child with the common prefix in the current node's children
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                        auto itNewChild = currentNode->children.find(edgeKey);//, std::move(newChild));
                        itNewChild->value = std::move(newChild);
                        rollbackLocation = itNewChild->value.get();
                        currentNode = itNewChild->value.get();
#else
                        auto itNewChild = currentNode->children.emplace(commonPrefix[0], std::move(newChild));
                        currentNode = itNewChild.first->second;
#endif
                    } else {
                        // Entire edge is a common prefix, proceed with the child node
                        currentNode = childNode;
                        if(currentNode->isEndOfWord && currentNode->deleted)
                        {
                            //if the current node is deleted, then we can insert the value here
                            currentNode->value = std::move(value);
                            currentNode->deleted = false;
                            inserted = currentNode;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Update the remaining part of the key to insert
                    remaining = remaining.substr(commonPrefixLength);
                } else {
                    // No common prefix found, create a new edge for the remaining part of the key
                    auto newNode = make_unique_alloc<FlashRadixTreeNode>(_nodeAllocator, remaining, std::forward<Value>(value), currentNode);
                    const char newKey = remaining[0];
                    typename FlashRadixTreeNode::Children::iterator lowerBound;
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                    if(_firstWord)
                        lowerBound = currentNode->children.find_predecessor(newKey);
                    
                    auto itNewNode = currentNode->children.insert(newKey, std::move(newNode));
                    inserted = itNewNode->value.get();
#else
                    if(_firstWord)
                    {
                        lowerBound = currentNode->children.lower_bound(newKey);
                        if(lowerBound != currentNode->children.end())
                        {
                            if(lowerBound->first == newKey)
                                --lowerBound;
                        }
                    }
                    auto itNewNode = currentNode->children.emplace(newKey, std::move(newNode));
                    inserted = itNewNode.first->second.get();
#endif
                    itNewNode->value->isEndOfWord = true;
                    
                    //update the firstword
                    if(_firstWord == nullptr)
                        _firstWord = inserted;
                    else if(lowerBound != currentNode->children.end())
                    {
                        auto* lowerNode = lowerBound->value.get();
                        if(!lowerNode->children.empty())
                            lowerNode = _getMaximum(lowerNode);
                        inserted->prev = lowerNode;
                        inserted->next = lowerNode->next;
                        lowerNode->next = inserted;
                    }
                    else if(currentNode->children.size() == 1) //no other children to link to so we link with the last node of the children above
                    {
                        auto* parent = currentNode->parent;
                        if(parent)
                        {
                            auto* last = parent->children.rbegin()->value.get();
                            last->next = inserted;
                            inserted->prev = last;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    // As we've inserted the rest of the key, we're done
                    remaining = Key();
                    currentNode = inserted;
                }
            }
            if(inserted == nullptr)
                return _endIt;
            else
            {
                ++_size;
                return iterator(inserted, this);
            }
        }
        catch (const std::bad_alloc&)
        {
            if(rollback.has_value())
            {
                //override the rollback location with the rollback node
                *rollbackLocation = std::move(_mergeFromNoOwnerNode(rollback.value(), rollbackLocation));
            }
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
    }
    
        
    //_erase() requires the function append() which will not work on a string_view.
    //in which case we use mark_erase()
    bool erase(const Key& key)
    {
        if constexpr(IsBasicString<Key>)
            return _erase(key);
        else
            return _mark_erase(key);
    }
    
    void print() const  {
        _printRecursively(' ', _root.get(), 0);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    iterator find(const Key& key) const {
        if (key.empty()) {
            return _endIt; // An empty key cannot be found.
        }
        
        auto* currentNode = _root.get();
        auto keyPrefix = key[0];
        Key remaining = key;
        size_t seen = 0;
        while( currentNode != nullptr)
        {
            const auto& it = currentNode->children.find(keyPrefix);

             if(it != currentNode->children.end())
            {
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE) || defined USE_CHAR_MAP
                currentNode = it->value.get();
#else
                currentNode = it->second.get();
#endif
                if(MatchMode == MatchMode::Prefix && //if we are in prefix mode we can stop if we find the prefix
                   currentNode->isEndOfWord &&
                       (currentNode->children.empty() ||//if there are no children below this key we have our winner
                        currentNode->prefix.size() == remaining.size())) //if the prefix is the same size as the remaining key we can match on that also
                {
                    if(currentNode->deleted)
                        return _endIt;
                    else
                        return iterator(const_cast<FlashRadixTreeNode*>( currentNode), this);
                }
                else if(currentNode->isEndOfWord && remaining == currentNode->prefix) //else we no choice but to check the whole word
                {
                    if(currentNode->deleted)
                        return _endIt;
                    else
                        return iterator(const_cast<FlashRadixTreeNode*>( currentNode), this);
                }
                else if( key.size() > (seen += currentNode->prefix.size()) )
                {
                    //we look for children below looking at the next possible prefix
                    keyPrefix = key[seen];
                    remaining = key.substr(seen);
                }
            }
            else
                return _endIt; //assume doesn't exist
            
        }
        return _endIt;
    }
    
    //delete all items non recursively
    void clear()  {
        if(_root != nullptr)
            _root->clear();
        _root = nullptr;
        _size = 0;
        _firstWord = nullptr;
    }
        
private:
    void _printRecursively(const typename Key::value_type& key, FlashRadixTreeNode* node, int level) const {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
            std::cout << "  ";
        }
        
        std::cout << "K: " << key << " P: " << node->prefix << " (" << node->value << ")" << " is EOW " << (node->isEndOfWord ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;
        
#if defined( USE_SPLAY_TREE)
        for(const auto& it : node->children)
        {
            _printRecursively(it->key, it->value.get(), level + 1);
        }
#elif defined( USE_CHAR_MAP)
        node->children.inOrderAndOp([&](const auto& node)->bool {
            _printRecursively(node->key, node->value, level + 1);
            return true;
        });
#else
        for (const auto& it : node->children) {
            _printRecursively(it.first, it.second, level + 1);
        }
#endif
    }
  
        
        
    bool _mark_erase(const Key& key)
    {
        auto found = find(key);
        if (found == end()) {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            found->deleted = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    bool _erase(const Key& key)  {
        if (key.empty()) {
            return false; // Cannot erase an empty key
        }

        FlashRadixTreeNode* currentNode = _root.get();
        FlashRadixTreeNode* parentNode = nullptr;
        Key remainingKey = key;

        // Step 1: Find the node
        while (currentNode != nullptr && !remainingKey.empty()) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            auto it = currentNode->children.find(remainingKey[0]);
            
            if (it == currentNode->children.end()) {
                return false; // Key not found
            }

            const Key& nodePrefix = it->value->prefix;
            FlashRadixTreeNode* childNode = it->value.get();

            if (remainingKey.starts_with(nodePrefix)) {
                // Prefix matches, move to the next node
                const auto nodePrefixSize = nodePrefix.size();
                remainingKey = remainingKey.substr(nodePrefixSize);
                currentNode = childNode;
            } else {
                // Prefix does not match the remaining key
                return false; // Key not found
            }
        }

        // If the end of the key has been reached and it's not marked as an end of a word, the key does not exist
        if (!currentNode->isEndOfWord) {
            return false;
        }

        // Step 2: Delete the node or unmark the end of the word
        currentNode->isEndOfWord = false; // Unmark as the end of a word

        // If the current node has has more than one child then we're done
        if (currentNode->children.size() > 1) {
            --_size;
            return true;
        }

        // Step 3: Clean up the tree
        if ((parentNode != nullptr) && (currentNode->children.size() <= 1) && !currentNode->isEndOfWord) {

            // Remove the leaf node if it does not have any children
            if(currentNode->children.empty())
            {
                //tidy up linked list of end of words
                if(currentNode->prev)
                    currentNode->prev->next = currentNode->next;
                if(currentNode->next)
                    currentNode->next->prev = currentNode->prev;
                    
                parentNode->children.erase(currentNode->prefix[0]);
            }

            // If the parent node is now a leaf and is not an end-of-word node, set it as the current node for the next iteration
            if (parentNode->children.empty() && !parentNode->isEndOfWord) {
                currentNode = parentNode;
                if (parentNode != nullptr) {
                    remainingKey = parentNode->prefix;
                }
            }
            else if(currentNode->children.size() == 1 && !currentNode->isEndOfWord)
            {
                auto remainingChild = std::move(currentNode->children.root()->value);
                //tidy up linked list of end of words
                if(remainingChild->prev)
                    remainingChild->prev->next = remainingChild->next;
                if(remainingChild->next)
                    remainingChild->next->prev = remainingChild->prev;
                
                currentNode->prefix.append(remainingChild->prefix);
                currentNode->value = remainingChild->value;
                currentNode->isEndOfWord = remainingChild->isEndOfWord;
                currentNode->children = std::move(remainingChild->children); //overrride children.
            }
            //if the parent node has only one child we can compress (unless we're root. that makes no sense)
            else if(parentNode != _root.get() && parentNode->children.size() == 1 && !parentNode->isEndOfWord)
            {
                auto remainingChild = std::move(parentNode->children.root()->value);
                //tidy up linked list of end of words
                if(remainingChild->prev)
                    remainingChild->prev->next = remainingChild->next;
                if(remainingChild->next)
                    remainingChild->next->prev = remainingChild->prev;
                
                parentNode->prefix.append(remainingChild->prefix);
                parentNode->value = remainingChild->value;
                parentNode->isEndOfWord = remainingChild->isEndOfWord;
                parentNode->children = std::move(remainingChild->children);
            }
        }
        --_size;
        return true;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _getMinimum() const  noexcept
    {
        auto* node = _firstWord;
        while(node != nullptr && (!node->isEndOfWord || node->deleted))
            node = node->next;
        return node;
    }
    
    FlashRadixTreeNode* _getMaximum(FlashRadixTreeNode* root) const  noexcept
    {
        if(root == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        
        auto* children = &root->children;
        auto it = children->rbegin();
        while( children != nullptr)
        {
            const auto check = children->rbegin();
            if(check == children->rend())
                break;
            it = check;
            children = &it->value->children;
        }
        auto* node = it->value.get();
        //hunt backwards for a node which is not deleted
        while(node != nullptr && (!node->isEndOfWord || node->deleted))
            node = node->prev;
        return node;
    }
    
    
    
    FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner _copyFromOwnerNode( FlashRadixTreeNode* node)
    {
        FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner newNode(node->prefix, node->value, node->isEndOfWord, node->parent);
        for(auto it : node->children)
            newNode.children.insert(it->key, it->value.get());
        
        return newNode;
    }
    
    //move from current node to rollback node if the child existed prior to the insert op
    FlashRadixTreeNode _mergeFromNoOwnerNode( FlashRadixTreeNodeNoOwner& node, FlashRadixTreeNode* current)
    {
        FlashRadixTreeNode newNode( node.prefix, std::move(node.value), node.isEndOfWord, node.parent);
        for(auto it :  node.children)
        {
            auto found = current->children.find(it->key);
            if(found != current->children.end())
                newNode.children.insert(it->key, std::move(found->value));
            
        }
        return newNode;
    }
    
};



template <Streaming Key, Streaming Value, MatchMode FindMode = MatchMode::Exact, typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Value>>>
class FlashRadixTreeSerializer {
    
public:
    std::string serialize(const FlashRadixTree<Key, Value, FindMode, Allocator>& tree) {
        return serializeNode(tree.getRoot());
    }
    
    std::string format(const std::string& serialized) {
        //iterate though string and insert new lines and tabs to format according to grammar
        std::string formatted;
        int indent = 0;
        for (auto c : serialized) {
            if (c == '[') {
                formatted += c;
                formatted += '\n';
                indent++;
                for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    formatted += '\t';
                }
            } else if (c == ']') {
                formatted += '\n';
                indent--;
                for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    formatted += '\t';
                }
                formatted += c;
            } else {
                formatted += c;
            }
        }
        return formatted;
    }

private:
    std::string serializeNode(const typename FlashRadixTree<Key, Value, FindMode, Allocator>::FlashRadixTreeNode* node) const  {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return "";
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "+[" << node->prefix << "," << node->value << "," << (node->isEndOfWord ? "√": "*")  << (node->deleted ? "X" : "") << ",<";

        if(node->children.empty())
            ss << "-";
        else
        {
            bool first = true;
#ifdef USE_SPLAY_TREE
            for(const auto& it : node->children)
            {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(it->value.get());
                first = false;
            }
#elif defined( USE_CHAR_MAP)
            node->children.inOrderAndOp([&ss, &first](const auto& childPair) -> bool {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(childPair.value);
                first = false;
                return true;
            });
#else
            for (const auto& childPair : node->children) {
                if (!first) {
                    ss << ",";
                }
                ss << serializeNode(childPair.second);
                first = false;
            }
#endif
        }
        
        ss << ">]";
        return ss.str();
    }
   
};

#endif /* FlashRadixTree */
```